# BIRT Xml DataSource with Multiple DataSets

Tags: xml, actuate

I am using one XML datasource in my report.

I have created multiple datasets for each complex tag that can repeat. I hava configure this Xml dataSource as URL, so I create five DataSets which DataSource is the Xml DataSource

```
URL.[UserValidation,DataValidation,Summary,CashException,PosException]
```

and it is work fine, and display what we want, but it send five times request to this URL.cause of the URL return same datas, in fact i just want to send one time and get datas to render this report.

Comment: we only can send one URL, and return all datas.  the five datasets return different records, but in one xml, and render complex report.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DataResponse>  
 <Validation> 
 <UserValidation authcode="1" ></UserValidation>
 <DataValidation countnum="1" ></DataValidation>
 </Validation>
<Summary>
 <rows>
  <row exctype="0" /> 
  <row exctype="0" /> 
 </rows>
</Summary>
<CashException> 
 <rows>
  <row aa="1985" cc="dd"/> 
  <row aa="1985" cc="aa" /> 
 </rows>
 </CashException>
<PosException>
 <rows>
  <row bb="oct 10" /> 
  <row bb="oct 11" /> 
 </rows>
 </PosException>
</DataResponse>